# Clash, crash and crush

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

I have never run across all those words. They seem not only close in sound but be used in similar situations (according to my research), that I sometimes become unable to choose which one to use.

The Merriam-Webster says (excerpt):

[**Clash**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clash)

> intransitive verb
>
> 1. to make a clash <cymbals *clashed*>
> 2. to come into conflict <where ignorant armies *clash* by night — Matthew Arnold>; *also* :  to be incompatible <the colors *clashed*>
>
> transitive verb
>
> :  to cause to clash

[**Crash**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crash)

> transitive verb
>
> 1. - a:  to break violently and noisily :  SMASH
>    - b:  to damage (an airplane) in landing
> 2. - a:  to cause to make a loud noise <*crash* the cymbals together>
>    - b:  to force (as one's way) through with loud crashing noises
>
> 4:  to move toward aggressively (as in fighting for a rebound) <basketball players *crashing* the boards>
>
> 5:  to cause (a computer system, component, or program) to crash
>
> intransitive verb
>
> 1. - a:  to break or go to pieces with or as if with violence and noise
>    - b:  to fall, land, or hit with destructive force
>    - c:  to decline suddenly and steeply
>    - d *of a computer system, component, or program* :  to suffer a sudden major failure usually with attendant loss of data
> 2. to make a smashing noise <thunder *crashing* overhead>
> 3. to move or force one's way with or as if with a crash <*crashes* into the room>

[**Crush**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crush)

> transitive verb
>
> - 1
>
>   - a:  to squeeze or force by pressure so as to alter or destroy structure <*crush* grapes>
>   - b:  to squeeze together into a mass
> - 3:  to reduce to particles by pounding or grinding <*crush* rock>
> - 4
>
>   - a:  to suppress or overwhelm as if by pressure or weight
>   - b:  to oppress or burden grievously <*crushed* by debt>
>   - c:  to subdue completely
>
> intransitive verb
>
> 2. to become crushed
> 3. to advance with or as if with crushing

From above, many questions arise. For example:

- *clash(intr.) 1* and *crash(tr.) 2a* (= *crash(intr.) 2*?) shares similar examples but does it mean they're synonymous in this way?
- Definitions in *crash* use "break" while *crush* use "squeeze", and does it mean *crush* is a subtype of *crash*, or the two are separate in manner of using forces?
- Is, perhaps, the choice of *crash* and *crush* predictable from the object? Which is more correct to say "His dream was crashed." and "His dream was crushed."?

Ultimately, if possible, I want to know whether, for native speakers, these words indeed share some kind of base sense but differ due to external factors, or are essentially different but have many common usages. If the latter, what's the crucial difference between them?

Comment: Excellent edit. This question should get less close votes and more upvotes now that you've pasted some definitions from a reputable dictionary. Now, the people who want to answer your question can spend less time consulting a dictionary to double-check their answer and more time focusing on the differences between the three words. I appreciate the way you've told us what you've already learned about the three words through your research. +1.

Comment: I just came across this question in the review queue and I didn't understand why it was getting close votes until I read JR's comment. It was a very good edit, especially your explanation of why the definitions are confusing, and I'm voting to leave this open.

Comment: I would use a second dictionary beside Merriam-Webster. Oald has much more examples. MW often gives only a meagre definition.http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/crash_2

Comment: A good question +1. Sometimes I wonder if I use which one, especially crash vs clash.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Interesting question.

Native speakers would treat the three words as have different and distinct meanings.
Only looking at the definitions it can be difficult to see the distinctions.

A **clash** is an **argument** or **confrontation**

> The two teams **clashed** on the football field. *( AmE use of football )*
>   The **clash** of the cymbals.  *( the hitting together )*

not to be confused with [The Clash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Clash).

A **crash** can mean a "loud sound" or the "forceful coming together"

> The **crashing** of helmets could be heard on every play when the teams **clashed**.
>   The **crash** of the cymbals. *( the loud sound )*

it is also used idiomatically in

> **car crash
>
>   plane crash**

meaning an **accident** since the accident can make a loud sound.  **Crash** can also mean **to break into** or **to sneak into** as in **gate crasher** or [Wedding Crasher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedding_Crashers)

To **crush** is to squeeze together

> The **crush** of bodies and the **crash** of helmets typified the annual **clash** between the two rival football teams.
>
> 96 people died in the [Hillsborough Disaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillsborough_disaster) which was a [human crush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stampede#Human_stampedes)

**Crush** also has a more positive connotation meaning **having an affection for** or **fondness for** more than "like" but less than "in love"

> a high school crush

and can be found here [Crush](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIhSnaqou0I)

Comment: Props for using them together in a sentence to illustrate the relative differences in meaning.

Comment: Thank you. Both answers are great but I'm going to accept this as I love the crush/crash/clash sentence.

Answer (score 5):

**To crash** is to come suddenly into contact with another object with great force. One object can be in motion and the other can be stationary; or both can be in motion.  A car can crash into a wall. Two cars, both in motion, can crash.

We do not say that the wall crashed into the car (unless the wall topples). Rather, the car crashes into the wall.  Similarly, if a car in motion crashes into a parked car, we do not say that "the two cars crashed".  The car in motion crashed into the parked car.

**To crush** is to apply force in a manner that causes something to become deformed.  The application of force can be sudden or gradual.

**To clash** is when two (or more) things  come together, with force. Both must be actively engaged in a course of action.  It can be used figuratively with parties (armies, institutions, countries, sports teams, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Two things *clash* if they don't mix or contrast greatly, especially in regards to visuality.  Usually these two things are abstract or nonphysical, like colors, or cultures, but things like parts of outfits can also clash.

X *crashes* if it collides with something at a high speed.  *Crash* is involved with a lot of slang use, e.g. it can mean to sleep on someone's couch, and software engineering uses the term to describe a program ending unexpectedly.

*Crush* means for something to be squeezed to death or to the point of being broken/damaged, typically from a weight at the top.  E.g. you crush autumn leaves (or bugs) with your foot.  There's a few slang uses for *crush* as well, e.g. "a crush" means you have an infatuation with someone.