# The meaning of "crash" in "The Wall Street crash in 1929"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I encountered a sentence from TOEFL text book.

Quote

> The Wall Street crash in 1929 threw the world economy into recession.

[Now according to the previous question,](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/85073/clash-crash-and-crush)

Since the best answer says "the incident can make sound", so that in this case, is that definition applicable too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the linked question, that one falls under

> intransitive verb
>
> 1. - c: to decline suddenly and steeply

The Wall Street Crash was a massive slump in stock market prices, which took the world economy with it.

Comment: I would add "and in so doing, causing great damage".  **crash** usually denotes damage.